# commercial application licensing issue and a solution for libpcap applications

Tags: c++, libpcap, tcpdump

I would like to develop some commercial tool in the area of processing data extracted out of a packet sniffer. I am aware that `libpcap` is available for that but I am quite sure that there are many restrictions due to licensing issues.

Suppose I don't link my application directly to `libpcap` libraries, but instead I use the output of `tcpdump` forwarded to a socket or to a pipe as a feed for my tool..do you think that I will be in trouble from a legal/licensing point of view?

Comment: libpcap uses the BSD license, which isn't very restrictive.  That said, for legal advice, talk to a lawyer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to look at [the license directly](http://www.tcpdump.org/license.html), which is a 3-clause BSD license. There is no restriction on the usage in commercial applications.

Reliable legal advice is most likely available from a lawyer of your choice.

Comment: HI. I would say that also a LGPL Vx looks nice. If your applications uses shared library there is no need to do anything (except to guarantee updates and include the LGPL licence ).